Host Static SPA written in HTML/JS in WebView2
I have created a Static SPA using SvelteKit, and i want to open the application in Revit using WebView2. The compiled file structure of my application looks like this:
build
- index.html
- favicon.png
- _app
  - env.js
  - version.json
  - immutable
    - chunks
      - disclose-version.BtJd_2Dd.js
      - entry.D6WgGb8s.js
      - proxy.C4KmojzZ.js
      - render.zjJFQd9i.js
      - runtime.4rquTwgo.js
    - entry
      - app.Cc30Kppw.js
      - start.BjQAhHL7.js
    - nodes
      - 0.rlw-XIZ8.js
      - 1.BWC29Vl1.js
      - 2.CteRqxFd.js

And my index.html file looks like this:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/entry/start.BjQAhHL7.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/entry.D6WgGb8s.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/runtime.4rquTwgo.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/entry/app.Cc30Kppw.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/render.zjJFQd9i.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/disclose-version.BtJd_2Dd.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/immutable/chunks/proxy.C4KmojzZ.js">
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents">
            <script>
                {
                    __sveltekit_v04hc = {
                        base: ""
                    };

                    const element = document.currentScript.parentElement;

                    Promise.all([
                        import("/_app/immutable/entry/start.BjQAhHL7.js"),
                        import("/_app/immutable/entry/app.Cc30Kppw.js")
                    ]).then(([kit, app]) => {
                        kit.start(app, element);
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

I have tried to host the application using npx serve and this works flawlessly.
Now i try to host it through WebView2. I write the following C# code:
webView.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
    "app.revitfoundry",
    "C:\\path\\to\\my\\app\\build",
    CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow
);

webView.Source = new Uri("https://app.revitfoundry/index.html");

When loading the web view, the application loads, but my application cannot find the index.html file:
Could not find /index.html

When inspecting the webview, all the files within the HTML/JS application are loaded into "Sources" and are stored in top->app.revitfoundry. Even the index.html file is stored here, which the application seems not to be able to find.
What could cause the error? Is it something with Svelte? If so, then i find it weird that the code works when running a server using npx serve. Is it maybe something wrong with the configurations of the webView?
